# How do I filter through a nested array in react?

Tags: reactjs, arrays, filter, nested

I'm trying to filter through an array and then a nested array within that array, in the same function.

It works fine while filtering through `keysFirst` and `keysSecond`.

The person array has two nested arrays: `skills` and `roles`. The `skills` array has an attribute of name and an attribute of stars. Here I want to filter on the name attribute.

How do I make a function where I'm able to filter through either `keysFirst` and/or `keysSecond` and also through one or both of the nested arrays?

Hope that makes sense.

Homepage.jsx

```
const [queryText, setQuery] = useState("");
const [querySecond, setQuerySecond] = useState("");
const [queryThird, setQueryThird] = useState("");

const keysFirst = ["firstname", "lastname"];
const keysSecond = ["location", "department"];
const keysThird = ["skills", "roles"];

const [data, setData] = useState([
    {
      firstname: "Brad",
      lastname: "Pitt",
      location: "America",
      department: "Hollywood",
      skills: [
        { name: "Actor", stars: 5 },
        { name: "Fighting", stars: 4 },
      ],
      roles: [
        { name: "Snatch", salary: 1000 },
        { name: "Fightclub", salary: 2000 },
      ],
    },
    {
      firstname: "Jason",
      lastname: "Statham",
      location: "England",
      department: "Hollywood",
      skills: [
        { name: "Driving", stars: 2 },
        { name: "Taxi", stars: 4 },
      ],
      roles: [
        { name: "Crank", salary: 3000 },
        { name: "Transporter 2", salary: 4000 },
      ],
    },
  ]);

const searchFunction = (data) => {
    const personFiltered = data.filter(
      (item) =>
        keysFirst.some((keysFirst) =>
          item[keysFirst].toLowerCase().includes(queryText.toLowerCase())
        ) &&
        keysSecond.some((keysSecond) =>
          item[keysSecond].toLowerCase().includes(querySecond.toLowerCase())
        )
    );
    return personFiltered;
  };
```

Comment: Please attach sample `data` parameter value passed to the function.

Comment: I have now made an edit with the ```data``` parameter (just an example). Hope that helps.